# Large Categorical Value in Pandas

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

i want to convert my categorical value into one hot encoding/get_dummies but i am having 4340 unique categorical value. I am getting memory error because of this. How can i handle this type of large categorical values.

**Update:**

Since the data is sensitive so i can not post all the data i am giving the column name something different but the values are like that and since it is not possible to post all 4340 unique categorical values i am giving small sample.

```
index|   ID
-------------
46   |    R05
61   |  M9901
72   |   J301
103  |   F411
135  |   R070
139  |   J069
```

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Comment: @jezrael please check

Comment: It is more complicated as seems, maybe check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44232474), but if native function is slow is possible use server with more `RAM` (what is practically very often not possible :()

Comment: How many rows (data samples) do you have? 4320 categories will be converted into `number of rows x 4320 columns`, So I think you have too many rows? Now if you have the list of all the categories. So it all depends on the usage of data after one-hot encoding. Have you tried [LabelEncoder + OneHotEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48079345/3374996)? OneHotEncoder will return sparse matrices which will save you memory.

Comment: but is it a good approach to have 4320 columns ?

Comment: That is an entirely different question. You can replace very rarely occuring categories with a new fixed category ("Others", or "Unknown" etc), which will bring down the columns. But then you need to make sure that it does not affect the performance much.